# How to derive the probability density function (PDF) of a continuous random variable from a set of data?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function, sampling

I am interested to derive an expression for the probability density function (PDF) of a continuous random variable from a given set of data. To further explain, let us consider that we have the data of time spent by visitors to a web page for a 24 hours period. At certain hours, say during the busy hours of day, the time spent on the web page is short. However, in the afternoon the time spent is long. I would like to derive an expression for the PDF of the continuous random variable X representing the time spent by the visitor, such as,

$$
f_X(x)=
\begin{cases} 
24x-x^2, \quad x > 0\\
0, \quad\quad\quad\quad \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

This is only an assumed PDF. I have tried to search but did not find an appropriate answer to this question. Most of the books on probability teach you how to derive probability values when given a PDF and all other sorts of things. However, the PDF is always given or assumed. So, my questions are:

1. Do we always assume or try to map a suitable PDF from the set of popular distributions, such as Gaussian, exponential, log normal and so on for a given set of data? If yes, is there any standard way to do this?
2. Is it possible to derive a mathematical equation for the PDF of the random variable from a given set of sample data? If yes, how this could be done? Is there any branch of Statistics and Probability Theory dealing with this?

I would much appreciate any answers to these questions. Pointers to any resources or books or chapters will also be helpful.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we always assume or try to map a suitable PDF from the set of
>   popular distributions?

No, the manner of pdf depends on the (real) situation. Your pdf should meet two requirements:

- It must be defined between 0 and 24.
- The pdf has a maximum at noon.

The second requirement is met at your pdf. Let $x=12$ be the noon then f(x) has a maximum at noon. The first requirement we can defined by $0<x\leq 24$.  Additionally we have the property that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \ dx =1$. To fulfill this condition we multiply the function by a constant $c$ and determine then the value of $c$.

$$c\cdot \int_0^{24} 24x-x^2 \, dx=1$$

It comes out that $c=\frac1{2304}$. Thus one possible pdf is

$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}\frac1{2304}\cdot \left( 24x-x^2\right), \ 0<x\leq 24 \\ 0, \ \text{elsewhere} \end{cases} $$

Other suitable pdf´s are possible.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my proposed PDF. It should have been multiplied by a constant with the correct specification of the region of non zero probability.

Comment: @AdnanAli You´re welcome. Yes, that´s the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Question 2) is one of the basic field of investigation of statistics, 
in particular [sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(statistics)) and [distribution fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution_fitting).

Concerning question 1) there is such a plethora of distributions, derived from a wide set of theoric and applicative scenarios,
 that it is highly "un-probable" that you might need a new one.

And in fact your *parabolic* PDF, which shall actually read as
$$
PDF \propto {x \over {24}}\left( {1 - {x \over {24}}} \right) \propto \xi \left( {1 - \xi } \right)
$$
is just a particular case of a [Beta Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution).

Comment: @G Cab, Did you mean $PDF \propto 24x(1-\frac{x}{24}) \propto \xi(1-\xi)$

Comment: well, it is a matter of how you measure the time and transform to get a $0 \le \xi \le 1$: if $x$ are the hours, ranging $0$ to $24$  then $\xi =x/24$.  However $PDF \propto 24x(1-\frac{x}{24})=x(24-x) \propto \frac{x}{24} (1-\frac{x}{24}) \propto \xi(1-\xi)$

Comment: $\xi$ of course is time measured in fraction of a day.